# How to access to namespace in declare global?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, multer

## Background

I'm making simple website in which user can update picture.
So, I'm using Multer library and Express with Typescript.

## Problem

I want to use [File type of Multer](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/022dbd5d9115992722c50043b930b2dbafa94b43/types/multer/index.d.ts#L102). But I don't know how to access Multer namespace.

```
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request {
      file: Multer.File;
      files: {
        [fieldname: string]: Multer.File[];
      } | Multer.File[];
    }

  namespace Multer {
    interface File {
      /** Field name specified in the form */
      fieldname: string;
      ...
}
```

My Final goal is this.

```
app.post('/admin/uploads', async (req, res) => {
    let file: Multer.File = req.files.myFile;
    console.log(file.filename);
    ....
}
```

How to access to Multer namespace?

Comment: I am also want to access the variable (ex. Filename) out of the namespace... !

Answer (score 1):

```
app.post('/admin/uploads', async (req, res) => {
    let file: Express.Multer.File = req.files.myFile;
    console.log(file.filename);
    ....
}
```